# Drop all GET Parameters from main index file in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I would like to remove all GET parameters from the index file in the root folder, while leaving all GET parameters everywhere else.

Example:

http://support.oursite.com/?ref=inline

I would like that to get ported to

http://support.oursite.com/

While

http://support.oursite.com/tickets/?id=1934

Would still contain the ID parameter.

I have been able to wipe the parameters, what I'm looking for is help on *limiting that wipe to just the root index.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution to this, for anyone who comes across this issue.

I have two separate location parameters:

`location ~* ^/(.+)$ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1/$1$is_args$args;
}`

location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1/;
}

The use of the `(.+)` tells Nginx only run this location if there is something after the slash. Because GET parameters aren't processed in that spot, it's safe to do this.